# JQUERY AJAX Call - Function with Variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to make many JQUERY AJAX Calls but I don't want to repeat the AJAX call code constantly. Therefore I've tried to setup an AJAX Function as follows:

```
function ajaxCall(ajaxData) {
    $.post('scripts/ajax/connect.ajax.php', {
        ajaxData
    }, function(ajaxReturn) {
        if (ajaxReturn == 'deadSession') {
            location.reload();
        } else {
            return ajaxReturn;
        }
    });
}​
```

However the above code doesn't work because of the {ajaxData} variable in the AJAX Call. The following code does work:

```
function ajaxCall(ajaxData) {
    $.post('scripts/ajax/connect.ajax.php', {
        'googleMetaSave': '1'
    }, function(ajaxReturn) {
        if (ajaxReturn == 'deadSession') {
            location.reload();
        } else {
            return ajaxReturn;
        }
    });
}​
```

Is there any advice on how I can use a variable in the AJAX Call that is setup as required and then passed to this function.

Comment: Note that the ajax `success` function's return value is ignored, so there's no purpose served by your `return ajaxReturn;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jQuery POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method second parameter is expected to be either a string representing a series of key/value pairs, separated by `&`, or it must be a map containing the series of key value pairs.

Because of the loosely-typed nature of JavaScript, this isn't going to have a huge impact on your function.

Since the variable ajaxData represents the object being passed to the server, you don't need the extra `{}` around it as this is redundant, if you're passing an object, and syntactically incorrect if you're passing a string.

First, let's address the problem with your logic in the callback function. Since AJAX is asynchronous, your function will have completed it's execution before the callback function has fired. Instead, your `return ajaxReturn` statement returns a value to the callback function itself, which means the data goes nowhere.

In order to get the data to someplace where it can be processed, your callback must pass that data into another function as a handoff. I've modified your code, both removing the unnecessary, incorrect `{ }` around the ajaxReturn parameter, as well as eliminating the return statement.

```
function ajaxCall(ajaxData) {
    $.post('scripts/ajax/connect.ajax.php', 
        ajaxData   /* you don't need {} here */
    , function(ajaxReturn) {
        if (ajaxReturn == 'deadSession') {
            location.reload();
        } else {
            // return ajaxReturn;

            // hand the data off to a processing function
            processData(ajaxReturn);   
        }
    });
}​

function processData(data) {
    // do stuff with the data here
}
```

To invoke you're function and make a successful post call, it's helpful to see an example of how to create the string/object representing the parameters:

```
// put the data in an object. {} are needed here.
var myData = { 'googleMetaSave' : '1' };

// make a call to fire the ajax post request
ajaxCall( myData );
// execution stops here, as your callback will handoff the response
 // to your processData function.
```

Alternatively, instead of a JavaScript object, you can represent the POST data like so:

```
// represent data as a query string instead of object
var myData = 'googleMetaSave=1';

// send the data to the post function. 
ajaxCall( myData );
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the {} around ajaxData :

```
   function ajaxCall(ajaxData) {
    $.post('scripts/ajax/connect.ajax.php', ajaxData, function(ajaxReturn) {if(ajaxReturn == 'deadSession') {location.reload();}else{return ajaxReturn;}});           

}
```